# In Black Ops II zombies, what are the differences between public match and custom games?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

In Black Ops II zombies, what are the differences between public match and custom games?

The main difference that I know is that in custom match, randoms cannot search your game as in public match, but friends can join a game in progress.

Here are the descriptions in the zombies multiplayer menu:

- Public match:

  > Find and team up with fellow survivors to fight against unending waves of the undead, post to leaderboards, and review slaying stats.
- Custom games:

  > You make the rules! Play with fellow survivors and team up to fight unending waves of the undead.

Do custom games have the same leaderboards as public match? The custom games description excludes mentioning leaderboards and stats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Public match, you know it... playing with other players around the world online.

Custom Games: You make the rules.

1. When you are playing Tranzit, you can choose if you want to play with the original difficulty or "easy" difficulty which makes the game easier.
2. When you are playing survival or grief, you can choose the difficulty, the round you start at (1, 5, 10, 15, 20 only), whether you want to play with magic (mystery box, pack a punch, etc.), and whether you want to play a game where you can kill with headshots only.

**Custom games do not count for the leaderboards.**

Comment: If they have the same leaderboards and you start a custom game at wave 20 does that mark your score of public matches at wave 20 then? (if that is the highest you achieved of course).

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma Um, while writing this, I had made a mistake. Custom games do not count for the leaderboards.

Comment: Ah ok i thoughts so ;)